# When I upload image to Firebase, image url from Database Realtime is different image url from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

This is my code, i don't know why getDownloadUrl() give result is different than image url from storage.

```
final Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();

        mProgressUpload.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
        mProgressUpload.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        mProgressUpload.show();

        final StorageReference filepath = mImgStorage.child("cover_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");

        filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") final
                String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(imageUri);
                uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Map updateHashmap = new HashMap<>();
                            updateHashmap.put("cover", download_url);

                            mUserDatabase.updateChildren(updateHashmap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        mProgressUpload.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileSetting.this, "Update successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileSetting.this, "Update failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        mProgressUpload.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

[Image URL from Realtime Database](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chatio-2de82.appspot.com/o/cover_images%2Fw0nMktrwhqVMLxjoGfgdcOz3Q8t1.jpg?alt=media&token=6801723e-193f-48a8-a21c-9cdd99678f14)

[Image URL from Firebase Storage](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chatio-2de82.appspot.com/o/cover_images%2Fw0nMktrwhqVMLxjoGfgdcOz3Q8t1.jpg?alt=media&token=162f62ee-f49b-49c5-b41e-d54896c59c04)

Can you solve this ???

Comment: "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation". Add a printscreen or chage the permissions.

Comment: @Alex Mamo edited new link url

Comment: Show us please the code where you display the picture.

Comment: it's just imageView, bro :)) i using Picasso and load image from database to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's different because when you are uploading the image to `Firebase Storage` you are using a different url then you are using when you are adding the url to `Firebase Database`. First time you are using `imageUri` and second time you are using `download_url` which obvious are not the same. So in order to solve this problem, take the url of the file that you are uploading to storage and use it when you add it to database.

Hope it helps.